# Clearing Cookies

Tags: cookies

I have a website and I have configured it such that only once the user accepts the use of cookies on their website, cookies will be enabled.

I tried using javascript to delete all cookies on page load. But for some reason one cookie still remains.. and the cookie in itself and it's value are a string of junk characters.
Cookie name: SESSbcb9eecbd50e36ecb0e5050944c6a793
Cookie Value: r87wIdULAl26ZINb3F7QuCbajCwskPi99eEjJh6VtZ0

Based on what I have read online, cookies that are httpOnly cannot be deleted. Is this true? Can it be done through Drupal core itself? Please let me know. 
Thanks.

Comment: That's your browsers session with the server the site is running on. Not sure if you can not have that set its fairly important to everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are attempting to comply with the new EU privacy laws... I suggest you use https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance since they have done a lot of work to make sure that sites with this module installed are in compliance and as changes are needed the module will be updated.